# Rails send_data() send_file() problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a **paperclip** attachment in one model, but I`m not saving the file in /public, but /assets. And when the user what to open the file I use the send_data() function, which makes the user to download the file.

My question is how can I show the file in other way (not nessecery to download)? So if the file is a image, I will see it directly in the browser without download.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
send_data foo, :disposition => 'inline'
```

This would tell the browser to just render the content, instead of prompting the user to save it.

… from http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data